# Elements not going into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am having an issue with my characters going into my array, this is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "graph.h"


void getfile(char[], char[]);
void reachable(char[]);

int size;
int i;

////////////GETFILE FUNCTION/////////////

void getfile(char *graph, char *source) {
    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen(graph, "r");

    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file %s!\n", graph);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(infile, "%s", &source[i]) != EOF) {
        ++i;
    }
    fclose(infile);

    size = strlen(source);
    printf("%s\n", source);


    reachable(&source[0]);
}

///////////REACHABLE FUNCTION////////////
void reachable (char *source){
char odd[100];
char even[100];

//printf("%s\n", odd);
//printf("%s\n", even);

    int i;


    for (i = 0; i<size; i+=2){
//        printf("%c", source[i]);
         odd[i] =  source[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){
        even[i] = source[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n", odd);
}
```

Output:

```
rlxrtgacufkrzyngilzxazrasjsbjqqitxmewplhtwzgxhokfmadrv
r
rlxrtgacufkrzyngilzxazrasjsbjqqitxmewplhtwzgxhokfmadrv
```

The commented line in my first for loop under the "REACHABLE FUNCTION" correctly prints every other variable from the original source array. however when I add the `odd[i] = source[i]` it breaks and and only display the first line of the string that resides in my array `source`.

This is the output I'm trying to get when I print my  `odd` array:

```
rlxrtgacufkrzyngilzxazrasjsbjqqitxmewplhtwzgxhokfmadrv
rxtaukznizarssjqtmwltzxofar
```

Anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!
-OppositeIllusion

Comment: You never add a null terminator to the strings, so you're getting undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do you call these `even` and `odd`? `odd` has the even indexes, and `even` contains all the indexes.

Comment: Where does `size` come from?

Comment: You're only filling in every other element of `odd`, so you're printing whatever happened to be in the other elements.

Comment: well yes the name of the arrays may be switched around however that can be easily fixed. `size` comes from `size = strlen(source);` this line of code.

Comment: `while (fscanf(infile, "%s", &source[i]) != EOF) {++i;}` You read strings and store in adjacent character positions. That will discard most of each string. Only first character will be kept except for the last string.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

1. Your are stepping through the source in leaps of 2 `i+=2` but you should not be also stepping through your output `odd[]` in leaps of 2. That index should advance by one each iteration.
2. You are not null terminating your strings. printf will continue trying to print characters until it reaches a character of value 0. So the string "Hello" is actually 6 bytes, not 5, because there is an invisible 0 at the end to tell printf and kin when the string has ended. And that is the actual number zero x[end] = 0; (correct), not the char x[end] = '0'.

Comment: So would I fix this by creating a nested for loop only incremeting by 1 each time and put that through `odd`? And for problem number 2, just create a null terminator for my arrays?

Comment: Use two counters. writeIndex and readIndex. Then in the loop, writeIndex+=1, readIndex+=2; You can do this in the body of the loop or in the last part of for(;;) using the comma. You can also just increment n by one and write odd[n] = odd[n*2+1] using that same math expression in the condition: n*2+1<size.

Comment: Just saw an error in my last comment. Should be odd[n] = source[...